# When should I overload the co_await operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20, language-design, c++-coroutine

I have recently discovered that the following code is legal:

```cpp
struct S {
    void operator co_await();
};
```

Why is `co_await` an overloadable operator? Why would I want to overload it, and what is the idiomatic way to do so?

The [cppreference article on couroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines#co_await) mentions that if no `co_await` operator exists, an awaiter is awaitable as-is, so it seems optional.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an object that has been given an awaitable object by someone else. And you want your object to be awaitable, but all you're going to do with the await machinery is forward those calls directly to this internally stored object. You don't want to inherit from the given awaitable class for various reasons.

So you overload `operator co_await`, such that you return a reference to this awaitable. That object is the one that has all of the await calls; you're just an intermediary.

Comment: What is the relationship between overloading `operator co_await` vs defining `await_transform`?

Comment: @Dejavu: Location. `await_transform` is a member of the *promise* object; it applies to every `co_await` used in every single coroutine which uses that promise type. `operator co_await` is a member of the object that wants to be awaitable. If both are available, both are used, with `await_transform` going first, and `operator co_await` looked up by the result of that.

Comment: So foundamentally they serve similar purposes right? Like no one is "better" than another semantically, just "Location", right?

Comment: @Dejavu: I wouldn't say that they serve similar purposes. It's better to say that they both interact in the same process, but usually for entirely different *reasons*. You use `operator co_await` to forward an awaitable through your own type. You use `await_transform` because the promise wants to interact with the awaitable before awaiting on it. You are either writing an awaitable or writing a promise. So you should never be trying to pick one over the other.